# AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'addJar'

Tags: pyspark, mqtt

I need to add some external dependent library(`spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-1.5.2.jar` in my case) to my pyspark word count code.  I know we can add external jars with –jars property in spark submit or running with pyspark shell. But I want to add this jar in my code or in spark config file. I found that we have `SparkContext.addJar()` method , which can be included in code.

```
sc.addJar("spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-1.5.2.jar")
```

But the above command is giving me error: `AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'addJar'`.

I have tried adding this jar in Spark_default.config file as :

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-1.5.2.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-1.5.2.jar
```

But this is also not working for me. I have looked in internet but not getting any useful link.

I am using Spark 1.5.2 with 1 namenode and 3 datanode in HDP cluster.

Can you please help me in solving the issue. It will be really thankful of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me by adding external dependency in spark_deafult.config as

spark.jars spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-1.5.2.jar

Now my job is taking external dependency.

Answer (score 1):

`spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` will work, but this should be paths your Hadoop nodes as this files are not uploaded, they are just added to spark containters classpath.